# Make an unique result from a relationship in Laravel be an object instead of an object within an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, relationship

My query to fetch the related user results in an object inside of an array

```
$members = CalendarMembers::with("user")
    ->where('calendar_id', $calendar[0]->calendar_id)
    ->get();
```

has this relationship

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Users::class, "id", "user_id");
}
```

and it results in

```
"status": "200",
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "member_id": 4,
        "calendar_id": 4,
        "invited_by": null,
        "color": "#7D96E1",
        "role": "parent",
        "added_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49",
        "user": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "User Name",
                "email": "username@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "User",
                "last_name": "Name",
                "status": "active",
                "is_activated": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49"
            }
        ]
    },
```

But it will always be one `User`, therefore I am trying to change the `user` to a simple object:

```
"status": "200",
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "member_id": 4,
        "calendar_id": 4,
        "invited_by": null,
        "color": "#7D96E1",
        "role": "parent",
        "added_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49",
        "user": {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "User Name",
                "email": "username@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "User",
                "last_name": "Name",
                "status": "active",
                "is_activated": 0,
                "created_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49",
                "updated_at": "2018-02-07 09:06:49"
            }
    },
```

But no success on finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->hasMany(Users::class, "id", "user_id")
```

to

```
$this->hasOne(Users::class, "id", "user_id")
```

Comment: I overlooked `hasOne`, damn it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will return the collection as it has hasMany relation

```
 $this->hasMany(Users::class, "id", "user_id");
```

Make sure the relation is given properly.
if your requirement is single user use the below code:

```
$this->hasOne(Users::class, "id", "user_id");
```